# xarray - Resample time-series data by arbitrary time period

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a time-series DataArray object with xarray.

The `time` dimension starts from 2000-01-01 to 2000-12-31.

```
<xarray.DataArray '__xarray_dataarray_variable__' (time: 365, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>

Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-03 ... 2000-12-31
```

What I want to achieve is to resample the data for variable "`__xarray_dataarray_variable__`" by March-June and July-November so this is excluding the summer days.

I have been trying to use the resample function but have no luck how to resample into uneven time periods.

```
da.resample(time='XXX').sum('time')
```

I am assuming I will have to use `pandas` but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the impression that you are misusing the term "resample". I can understand that you are trying to sum all the points in a period, then you try something like this:

```
da_march_to_june = da.sel(time = slice('2000-03-01', '2000-06-30')).sum(dim = 'time')
da_july_to_november = da.sel(time = slice('2000-08-01', '2000-11-30')).sum(dim = 'time')
```